# Is there a good alternative for "passion" in "my passion in some subject is ignited"?

Tags: synonyms

Is there a good alternative for "passion" in "my passion in certain subject was ignited"? I have used the word "passion" just a few sentences ahead in the same article "my passion for certain subject is noteworthy". Thanks!

Comment: I personally prefer either *my dedication* or *my commitment*.

Comment: +1 for "commitment"... Hope you don't mind I stole your suggestion (with credit, of course). :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT.: Thanks! "my commitment/dedication in some subject is noteworthy." but not "my commitment/dedication in some subject is ignited"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer either ***my dedication*** or ***my commitment***.

As for the further question in a comment: *"my commitment/dedication in some subject is noteworthy,"* but not *"my commitment/dedication in some subject is ignited"*? I think you should use

> *... my commitment/dedication **to** some subject is noteworthy.*

I believe that you can say something ***ignited my passion ...***. However, if you are talking about something that got your intention and brought you into the field for the first time, using *piqued my interest* might sound better. For example,

> *While I was researching into the field privately, I found a great article from your university that **piqued my interest** in learning more about the field. ...*

You can even add *pursue my passion*, if you prefer, e.g.

> *... and I **have pursued my passion** ever since.*

Comment: One more option (not really worth its own answer, but perhaps worth mentioning here nonetheless): **kindled my enthusiasm**.

Answer (score 1):

They're not exactly synonyms, but they may still be appropriate given the context:

> excitement (about)
>   dedication (to)
>   devotion (to)
>   commitment (to) (hat tip:@Damkerng)

Comment: I answered the question too, for OP's alternatives. Hope you don't mind. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Definitely not! I'm glad you placed your examples in context. :-)